# set validation if radio button selected Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

So i have two radio button named Result that have value Fit and Unfit. And one form input that named Detail. If the Unfit is checked then the Detail must be filled. How do i set the validation. currently i have callback function in the controller like this:

```
public function _is_detail_required()
{
    $result = $this->input->post('Result', true);
    if ($result != 'Unfit') {
        $detail = $this->input->post('Detail', true);
        if ($result == 'Unfit') {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('_is_detail_required', '%s harus diisi.');
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

and this is the validation rules (on models directory) that i set for the Detail:

```
$form_rules = array(
array(
        'field' => 'Result',
        'label' => 'Result',
        'rules' => 'trim|xss_clean|required|max_length[50]'
    ),
array(
        'field' => 'Detail',
        'label' => 'Detail',
        'rules' => 'trim|xss_clean|callback__is_detail_required|max_length[50]'
    )
);
```

my problem is, this callback function is not working. how do i fix this? Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback function that I wrote is wrong, it didnt check if the input form (Detail) is empty, so this is the correct one

```
public function _is_detail_required()
{
$result = $this->input->post('Result', true);
if (! empty($result) && $result == 'Unfit') {
    $detail = $this->input->post('Detail', true);
    if (empty($detail)) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('_is_detail_required', '%s harus diisi.');
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add this in your form validation:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
if ($CI->input->post('Result') == 'Unfit') {
    $form_rules[] = array(
       'field' => 'Detail',
       'label' => 'Detail',
       'rules' => 'trim|xss_clean|required|max_length[50]'
   );
}
```

Note: If your validation is located in your controller, use `$this`. If not, use `$CI =& get_instance();` instead.

Comment: My validation is located on models directory, I will try your code